# What is the angular registerControl() method for

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I saw that angular form had the following method `registerControl()`, but I couldn't really understand its usage.
Does somebody have a nice explanation and a use case for it?

I have the feeling I'm missing something that could be useful.

Thx for your help.

#### Edit

I already read the [angular explanation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#registercontrol) but couldn't understand it

Comment: Please check this link "https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/formgroup-in-angular/"

Comment: Thx @RaviAshara. But this article is basically duplicating the information we can already find on the angular official tutorial. Which didn't helped me in that specific case. (I've edited my initial question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.1.x/packages/forms/src/model.ts

Basically, we add another control to the form without invoking a check on value and validity, so there won't be many cases when you want to use it.

The only case which comes to my mind atm is when you want to register multiple controls without invoking value and validity check and invoke such check manually after you add all controls which you need so it would be triggered only once.

For example if I use addControl 3 times it would invoke updateValueAndValidity 3 times. But if I first registerControl 3 times and then manually invoke updateValueAndValidity or SetControl etc. on those 3 new controls then it would be invoked only once.

To summarize, it seems to be more about optimization. I didn't create any check for it but to be honest I would be surprised if that lead to a lot of saved time.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, I also though it was something like that.

Answer (score -3):

`registerControl()` method - Registers a control with the group's list of controls.

`registerControl(name: string, control: AbstractControl): AbstractControl`
Parameters:
`name`    :   `string`          The control name to register in the collection

`control`  :       `AbstractControl`     Provides the control for the given name

Returns
`AbstractControl`.

This method does not update the value or validity of the control.

For example if I use `addControl` 3 times it would invoke `updateValueAndValidity` 3 times, but if I first `registerControl` 3 times and then manually invoke `updateValueAndValidity` or `SetControl` etc. on those 3 new controls then it would be invoked only once.

To summarize, it seems to be more about optimization.

Comment: Hi, can you explain me how your answer is better than the already accepted one ?

Comment: And just, when you will explain, I suggest you to [edit] your answer and format the code as code with `